How to create a shortcut to open a folder inside Android/data?
So I have a path that is barely accessible by normal apps:
/sdcard/Android/data/com.zoiper.android.app/files/CallRecordings
Only the built-in Files app/UI can open it, and Total Commander can launch that pre-opened to this path. I'm trying to replicate that (Intent? Action?) and place a shortcut on my home screen that opens a UI to the contents of that folder (so I can move my call recordings to a normal place in the file system that gets synced to the cloud by other apps).
I don't know which intent/action can open that path. This page says that most of the normal ones (ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT) have restrictions against opening "The Android/data/ directory and all subdirectories."
I'm using the Shortcut Maker app so I don't need to write any code.
I go to Activities -> Files, and there is com.android.documentsui.ScopedAccessActivity which sounded promising.
Trying to figure out the exact intent/activity to use, and how to give it the path, and what the path should be in the Content URI scheme.
Something like this?
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fdata
I know it's doable since Total Commander can perform it, if it's possible to listen/log what went on in the system while TC opened the Files app, and I could inspect that info and replicate it as a shortcut it would be perfect.
Android 14, Samsung S24U

File permissions depend on Android version. Please [edit] your question to add Android version and device particular s. Also in tags

Granting general access to /Android/data  folders is no longer possible on Android 13 (and newer). IDK how Total Commander accessed them

If logcat -b events does not give you any hints you can try to run TC on a rooted device with magisk-frida installed and use frida-trace to get calls to startActivity. The correct filter should be -j '*!startActivity*'.
